# sstatic.net SSL certificate is for an incorrect domain

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, ssl

Noticing that the "Human Verification" image did not show, I found that the src, https://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/captcha-conchords-robots.jpg, shows that `sstatic.net` is giving an SSL vertificate for `*.stackexchange.com.`.

Comment: To clarify: *This is still a bug*, but the problem is that the URL for the image is wrong, not that the cert is incorrect. The problem can readily be fixed by the devs using the correct URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL should be corrected; the correct URL is:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/captcha-conchords-robots.jpg
```

which works just fine:

[image: Captcha Conchords Robots]

The `sstatic.net` domain is a named virtual host on the same machine as `stackoverflow.com`:

```
$ host sstatic.net
sstatic.net has address 198.252.206.16
$ host stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com has address 198.252.206.16
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 40 stackoverflow.com.s9b2.psmtp.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 10 stackoverflow.com.s9a1.psmtp.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 20 stackoverflow.com.s9a2.psmtp.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 30 stackoverflow.com.s9b1.psmtp.com.
```

but only one SSL cert can be used per IP address. This is why you see the wrong SSL cert being used.

The `cdn.sstatic.net` domain is the correct domain for the Stack Exchange CDN.

Comment: Works without the `cdn` subdomain as well once you bypass the browser warning. `https://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/captcha-conchords-robots.jpg` is the source used on the SO page.

Comment: @Mooseman: I know, but the `cdn.sstatic.net` domain uses the correct SSL cert. The `sstatic.net` domain is nothing but a virtual host on the same ip address as `stackoverflow.com.

Comment: So the problem is the source attribute, not the certificate.

Comment: You got it. :-)

Comment: "only one SSL cert can be used per IP address" With modern browsers you can use more. I think IE on WinXP is the only notable one that doesn't support [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Right, but until IE on WinXP and Android are sufficiently in the minority, options are limited.

Comment: Thank you for investigating this.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Bonus points if you fix(ed) the [related issue on Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/questions/4201/default-listing-images-arent-served-from-cdn-fail-to-load-because-of-certifica)! ;)

Comment: @Scott: this was a bug from 2013, there really is no point in correcting the image location in the “how the bug should be fixed” section. If anything the actual image should just be uploaded to Imgur.

Comment: So why don’t you rollback @Glorfindel’s edit while you’re at it?

Comment: Heh, it's really hard for my bot to figure out the intention of bug reports related to sstatic.net. Maybe I should resort to fixing these manually ...

Comment: @Scott: I hit the override on the suggested edit, which then is turned into a rollback. Glorfindel's edit was not a suggested edit.

Comment: @Glorfindel: I'd just leave old bug reports be. The circumstances are almost certainly different and loads of these will be broken just because they were localised to implementation details.