# Missing: Two Cardboard Robots!

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, captcha, broken-link

[The image](http://boingboing.net/images/roboboogie_07.jpg) that appears above the captcha seems to be broken.

[image: Eeek!]

(You can also [view a live version of this](https://stackoverflow.com/captcha))

This appears to affect [other](https://serverfault.com/captcha) [sites](https://superuser.com/captcha) [as](https://unix.stackexchange.com/captcha) [well](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/captcha), even though they use different images.

> Note that if you view the image URL directly and accept the SSL warning, all the images may *appear* to start working for you - but restarting your browser will reveal broken images again.

I actually encounter this captcha quite frequently due to writing up my answers in an external editor, and then pasting them in as a new response. I just started noticing the broken image today.

Comment: I think this one is worthy of an "Eeek!"

Comment: The possible-duplicate is closed as by-design - but it doesn't seem to have actually addressed the fact that the wrong URL is still being used.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Or Eeek! Is it [by design?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187348/187824)

Comment: @hims056 I didn't find that question when I searched, thanks. I interprete it as saying the certificate issues are by-design and pointed to the OP looking at the wrong URL - but it still didn't address the fact that the wrong URL is being used on the live sites.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Updated with a freehand circle **and** and an Eeek!

Comment: This is now Perfection!

Comment: See: _this_ is why we can't have nice things. The developers should've used jQuery to detect if the image loaded. If it can't, then switch it to a base64 encoded version saved in the JS file itself. If the JS can't be loaded, just use jQuery to fix that!

Comment: This looks like another victim of the SSL project. I really think it needs to be [added to the wheel of blame](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1430019#1430019).

Comment: @jcsanyi: I did not mean to imply that the OP of that report was using the wrong URL. I was pointing out that the real bug was that the *page* is using the wrong URL. Why it was marked as `status-bydesign` is beyond me, I'll flag the post.